# Google API malware warning

Tags: api, maps, malware

On my site but Securi SiteCheck is showing this:

*Anomaly behavior detected (possible malware). Details: http://sucuri.net/malware/malware-entry-mwanomalysp8

Is there anyway I can stop this malware warning for a fussy client?

Answer (score 1):

Go to wp-content/themes/header.php file and open it in NOTEPAD++ and if you see any JS code below, then simply remove that code...

Answer (score 0):

You have installed malware on your site (possibly your site was compromised) or your code looks like malware due to minified versions of JavaScript, which looks like obfuscated exploits.